# Adobe Digital Edition not opening in WIne

Tags: wine, ebooks, calibre, adobe-digital-editions

Been through all the posts out there and almost all are outdated. Installed latest Wine stable + wine-gecko-2.47.1. I then downloaded Adobe Digital Editions 4.5. Installation in Wine went smoothly. By mistake I installed twice, so now I have 2 ADE icons in my software menu (cannot find them to delete the one). However, when I try to open it, nothing happens. No response and no errors.

```
Dec 19 09:10:51 1 wine-Programs-Adobe-Adobe Digital Editions 4.5-Adobe Digital Editions 4.5.desktop[69115]: 0009:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
Dec 19 09:10:51 1 wine-Programs-Adobe-Adobe Digital Editions 4.5-Adobe Digital Editions 4.5.desktop[69115]: 0009:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00004100
Dec 19 09:10:51 1 wine-Programs-Adobe-Adobe Digital Editions 4.5-Adobe Digital Editions 4.5.desktop[69155]: The entry point method could not be loaded due to Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
Dec 19 09:10:51 1 systemd[2312]: app-gnome-wine\x2dPrograms\x2dAdobe\x2dAdobe\x20Digital\x20Editions\x204.5\x2dAdobe\x20Digital\x20Editions\x204.5-69115.scope: Succeeded.
```

Is the "PresentationFramework" the problem or a dependency missing? It's not very clear in the log error above.

I am trying to download my kobo books to add to Calibre.

Comment: Your post clearly says dependency is missing.

Comment: @David As it used the word "or" it wasn't so clear to me. Anyway, thanks for your insight. Do you know how I might find which dependency is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=33733 , seems to work for me

Post by spoon0042 » Sun Apr 19, 2020 2:44 pm Going by the [appdb page](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=33276) you will need 'winetricks corefonts dotnet40'. Info on winetricks is here: https://wiki.winehq.org/Winetricks

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post this.